# I am not getting laravel 8 jetstream profile photo path. it is saving on the storage

Tags: laravel-8

I am using jetstream. I am not getting the profile pic
[click on the picture][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DSjK.png
here is the devtool code

```
<img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover" src="http://jed.test/storage/profile-photos/zmgDcXE9utwTH7E3vwtt8YxnoHVsfxbDovb8UKiw.jpeg" alt="Rifat">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saving the image on the default disk (`config/filesystems.php`):

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
],
```

The image is saved in the `storage/app` folder, to access it you need to run `php artisan storage:link` and it will create a symbolic link on your public folder

Comment: storage:link  plus I updated my app_url in .env file. and now it is working fine